# Contract has not been deployed to detected network

Tags: web3js, truffle, truffle-deployment

I ran `truffle compile` and `truffle migrate` to  deploy my contract:

```
admin@admin-PC ~/Desktop/Coding Projects/truffleTestProject (master)
$ truffle migrate
Using network 'development'.

Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Deploying Migrations...
  ... 0xa8f3001d7778963ca08835f2d1c01c53e86dbb0922dfabcd3aca252d93ab6649
  Migrations: 0xb26e34c748a898f09af7e55875870f947b4d382b
Saving successful migration to network...
  ... 0xc38f5486655c640b692fedeb59d81217a94561e1c6b460dba3b608467e7815f4
Saving artifacts...
Running migration: 2_deploy_contracts.js
  Deploying CryptoSportsToken...
  ... 0x21d3bdfd5afe4ec96d5c37ff647f4a8fcf598272cd32e783edca47d601b47bcc
  CryptoSportsToken: 0xa076500eaafb7259535d3430e5eed8c2904651cb
Saving successful migration to network...
  ... 0x0dc395cdba01fcf01c2f2c89547bf001edc3ad7d0f69235f99e7ac48fb51fe12
Saving artifacts...
```

However, in my frontend I get the following message:

> Contract has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact
>   mismatch)

My folder structure looks like the following:

[image]

The `1_initial_migration.js` is the same as truffle created it in the beginning:

```
var Migrations = artifacts.require("./Migrations.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

My `2_deploy_contracts.js` file looks like the following:

```
var CryptoSportsToken = artifacts.require("CryptoSportsToken");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(CryptoSportsToken);
};
```

As you can see I only deploy my `CryptoSportsToken`. Within my CryptoSportsToken contract I am importing the  `"./ERC721.sol";`.

I further tried to use `truffle migrate --reset`, however it does not change anything on my output message.

Any suggestion  what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

**UPDATE**

I am using [truffle-contract](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract) to access the contract via web3.

See below my code how I access the contract in the frontend:

```
App = {
  web3Provider: null,
  contracts: {},

  init: function () {
    return App.initWeb3();
  },

  initWeb3: function () {

    // Is there an injected web3 instance?
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
      App.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider;
    } else {
      // If no injected web3 instance is detected, fall back to Ganache
      App.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545');
    }
    web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);

    return App.initContract();
  },

  initContract: function () {
    $.getJSON('CryptoSportsToken.json', function (data) {
      // Get the necessary contract artifact file and instantiate it with truffle-contract
      var CryptoSportsTokenArtifact = data;
      App.contracts.CryptoSportsToken = TruffleContract(CryptoSportsTokenArtifact);

      // Set the provider for our contract
      App.contracts.CryptoSportsToken.setProvider(App.web3Provider);

      return App.bindEvents();
    });
  },

  bindEvents: function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-create', App.createPerson());
  },

  createPerson: function () {
    //event.preventDefault();
    var cryptosportInstance;

    console.log("test")
    console.log(owner + " " + name + " " + price)
    console.log("###################")

    console.log("App: \n");
    console.log(App);
    console.log("App.contracts: \n");
    console.log(App.contracts);

    console.log("###################")
    console.log(App.contracts.CryptoSportsToken)

    web3.eth.getAccounts(function (error, accounts) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }

      var account = accounts[0];

      App.contracts.CryptoSportsToken.deployed().then(function (instance) {
        cryptosportInstance = instance;

        console.log(cryptosportInstance)

        var owner = $('#owner').val();
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var price = $('#price').val();

        return cryptosportInstance.createPromoPerson(owner, name, price).call();
      }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
      })
    });
  },
};

$(function () {
  $(window).load(function () {
    App.init();
  });
});
```

Further I created the [following github repo](https://github.com/marcpre/demo_truffle_cryptosports) to show all my current code.

**UPDATE 2**

The above code is from the `create_app.js` file and I am trying to make `create.html` work.

Comment: How do you access your contracts in the front end.

Comment: @Ismael Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 5):

> Contract has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact
>   mismatch)

I see <s>many</s> different problems with your code, but not what you mentioned in your question. I cloned your github repo and launched the app with `npm run dev`.

[image: screenshot]

---

**NOTE: Errors from the screenshot are not related to the original question.**

---

If you are curious these errors seem to happen because you are using `pet-shop-tutorial` `app.js` file without correct adaptation for your code.

*One function is simply missing in both `.js` files.*

*Also there might be a possible problem with binding function leading to incorrect sequence of code execution.*

*In the next lines you are declaring contract in `CryptoSportsToken` and right next line you are trying to `setProvider` to a contract `Adoption`, which was used in pet-shop-tutorial and obviously was overriden with your contract artifacts and name.*

```
App.contracts.CryptoSportsToken = TruffleContract(CryptoSportsTokenArtifact);

// Set the provider for our contract
App.contracts.Adoption.setProvider(App.web3Provider);
```

---

**[Edit 1]**

I launched `create.html` and it was sending some errors because of the function binding that I've mentioned above.

Fixed it with these lines:

```
bindEvents: function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-create', App.createPerson);
  },

  createPerson: function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
```

After I changed these lines I didn't make any changes and here is screenshot of your `create.html` page after succesfull transaction via MetaMask.
[image: screenshot]

To fix `createPromoPerson().call() is not a function` change your call to:

```
return cryptosportInstance.createPromoPerson.sendTransaction(owner, name, price);
```

---

*To run your code I simply renamed `create.html` to `index.html` because my purpose was only to test it and also question about how to make website with multiple pages is not related to Ethereum.*

Comment: Got the same issues.

Comment: @RomanFrolov Thx for your reply! Sorry the project is currently in progress. I am trying to make the `create.html` work, which uses the `create_app.js` file. Please be so kind to take a look at it. Thx

Comment: @Kare added new edit.